# socket.io configuration

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to set the configuration for socket.io as per https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

```
io.set('log level', 1);
```

But I'm getting TypeError: Object # has no method 'set' ... what's wrong? I have io = require("socket.io")

Also tried,

```
io.configure('production', function(){
    io.set('log level', 1);
});
```

but no luck. what's wrong ?

**EDIT:**

```
require.paths.push('/cygdrive/c/Personal/software/nodejs/NODE/node_modules');
var express = require("express"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    form = require('connect-form'),
    app = express.createServer(
        form({ keepExtensions: true })
    ),
    sys = require("sys"),
    RentModel = require("./rent_schema"),
    UserModel   = require("./track_schema"),
    io = require("socket.io"),
    fb = require('facebook-js'),
    Twitter = require('./Twitter_Analysis'),
    Foursquare = require('./Foursquare_Analysis'),
    YQL = require("yql"),
    settings = require("./settings");



socket = io.listen(app);
:::::::::::::::::
app.listen(9999);
```

This works fine.. But if I change it to io = require("socket.io")**.listen(8080)** it gives me error, listen method not found.

Answer (score 8):

`require('socket.io')` returns a Socket object. The set properties are on socket.io-manager. The manager is returned by `require('socket.io').listen(server)` call.

Note that you should be passing a web server to socket.io, not just a port:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io  = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.set('log level', 2);

app.listen(8080); // this is the server, not socket.io
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);` instead of just require.

Comment: My app works perfectly without listen(80)... wanted to add this configuration to reduce log level. When added listen(80) this also fails with error, node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Manager> has no method 'listen'

Comment: THat's because something is running on port 80

Comment: @Jason_King you listen to the http process, not the port, I believe

Answer (score 1):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.configure( function(){
    io.set('log level', 3);

});
```

There is one important thing to note here. If you get the error**process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick...** that means that you have another webserver, like Apache, listening to port 80.

So, if you chnage the port to, for example 8080, it should work:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.configure( function(){
    io.set('log level', 3);

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get the error on "listen", as, "TypeError: Object #<Manager> has no method 'listen'".... I am using express and listening at port 9999... is this causing the problem if I use require('socket.io').listen(9999) or listen(8080) ?? If i do not use listen as in require('socket.io').listen(9999), my application works perfectly fine.. But I needed to add "io.set('log level', 3);", but i can not as it says "has no method 'set'"

Comment: looks like you are not been able to "include" socket.io. That's why it works on the express server (app) and not on the socket server. try something like /socket.io or ../socket.io, pointing to the correct path.

Comment: The path seems to be correct.. if i use "/socket.io", it throws error, Error: Cannot find module '/socket.io'.. Also if it is not included, how does it work with express ?

Comment: Since I am listening as socket = io.listen(app) --- won't it be as follows ?
socket.configure('production', function(){
 socket.set('log level', 1);
});